# Total Internal Reflection

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

Which laws are obeyed during TIR, laws of reflection or refraction? I have worked on it and I found that both can't be obeyed during this. Please explain.

Comment: What exactly are the laws you are mentioning? The Snell's law and what else?

Comment: What type of explanation are you looking for? Why Snell's law fails for angles beyond the critical angle or what a more fundamental model of refraction and reflection would be?

Comment: Yes. Why the snell's law fails for angle above critical angle?

Comment: @GurbirSingh *To understand why light does this bending and reflecting at all, we can solve Maxwell's equations at the boundary of two materials with different indices of refraction*... https://van.physics.illinois.edu/QA/listing.php?id=42038&t=why-does-total-internal-reflection-happen

Comment: @GurbirSingh Check out this too....-http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_33.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which laws are obeyed during TIR, laws of reflection or refraction?

**Both**.

Before the total internal reflection (TIR) threshold, the ray can be both reflected and refracted *at the same time*: some of it stays in the material, the rest leaves it, so you have **two rays** leaving the interface. That the TIR takes place is precisely a consequence of the "refraction law".

> both can't be obeyed during this [TIR].

It doesn't make sense to state that: because these laws don't apply to the same ray, as the names in the Original Post makes clear. Beyond the critical angle, there is no refracted ray, and the reflected ray keeps obeying $\theta_r=\theta_i$, as it does for any angle.